# How does Fuel CMS update the database through Simple Modules?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fuelcms

I have a Simple Module called 'tradeusers' in my Fuel CMS/Codeigniter install. 
This lists trade users on the site from the tradeusers table in the DB.

This means my client will be able to update the info on the tradeusers from the CMS such as account number etc.

However, I want them to also be able to update the password for the user. This is currently stored as MD5 with SALT (please no SHA1 debate).

The password field is editable in the CMS but it will not encrypt as MD5 when changed. Is there a way I can make Fuel CMS/Codeigniter use MD5 for this field?

I know the fields are in the form_fields function in my model for this Simple Module but I can't see where the function is that then puts this data into the database.

I don't really want to create an Advanced Module for all of this as everything but this part is now ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your model:

```
public function on_before_save($values)
{
    $values = parent::on_before_save($values);

    $values['your_password_field'] = md5($values['your_password_field']);

    return $values;
}
```

Comment: Coming back years later to say the thanks I should have done then

Answer (score 2):

So you're looking to hash the plaintext password so it stores as MD5 in the tradeusers record? You could do that in your tradeusers model by running MD5 on the value before it saves.

http://docs.getfuelcms.com/general/models#hooks